# Bash script cannot run with keyboard shortcut

Tags: 14.04, unity, bash, scripts, shortcut-keys

I have this script in my `/home/username/`

And I can run it via terminal with the following code

```
./script.sh
```

or

```
sh script.sh
```

it works (it has executable permissions)

but I cannot assign it to a keyboard shortcut. I am adding the shortcuts with the "custom shortcut" tab of keyboard shortcuts. And also tried with xbindkeys, too.

What I've tried so far is (added them to command of the shortcut key)

```
bash "/script.sh"
bash "./script.sh"
bash "home/username/script.sh"
home/username/script.sh
sh "/script.sh"
"/script.sh"
/script.sh
gnome-terminal "/home/username/script.sh
```

and many more that I can't remember.

Can anyone tell the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a script to a keyboard shortcut:

1. *Unless* the script is in `$PATH` (like `~/bin`), use the *full path* to the script, don't use `~` or relative paths.
2. If you use full path, start (as always) with a slash, e.g.:

   ```
   sh /home/username/script.sh
   ```

   Your example doesn't :)
3. If your script is executable, *just* the full path will do:

   ```
   /home/username/script.sh
   ```

   if it isn't, use the preceding language, e.g.:

   ```
   sh /home/username/script.sh
   ```

#### What is the issue in your examples

In the attempts you show, you either use incorrect paths (`home/some_dir` is not a valid directory without a starting slash), you use another path then you mean to (`/script.sh` refers to your root directory) or you use relative paths. None of them will work from a shortcut key.

The same rules apply to Startup Applications by the way.

---

### EDIT

An additional issue in this case:

#### Your specific case; using an `xdotool` command in the script

From a comment, we found out the script you run uses an `xdotool` command, pressing keys:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool keydown Super key w
sleep 0.5 
xdotool keyup Super
```

Virtually pressing keys *from* a shortcut key combination will practically always lead to key- clashes, since the keys you *physically* press, will be combined with the ones you *virtually* press.

#### What to do

One way to avoid the issue is to give your fingers the time to "leave" the keys, to avoid the real keystrokes to be combined with the virtual ones. Even then though, you need to release the shortcut after you pressed them. The script then becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash
# here we add a little break to give your fingers 
# the opportunity to release the keys
sleep 0.5
xdotool keydown Super key w
sleep 0.5 
xdotool keyup Super
```

#### Note

If you are still having the issue, increase the time in line 4 (and only press the shortcut key shortly)

Comment: Hi @Jacob, thank you; tried but still not working. I use the same way for Startup app's, but for shortcuts, it is not working. Bizarre!..

Comment: Hi @AhmetSehaÇelenk silly suggestion, but could you try another key combination and/or remove the shortcut and recreate it with a (certainly) correct command? Custom shortcut keys can be stubborn sometimes, at least on 14.04., and this worked sometimes for me :). I've had a few situations in which the shortcut commands were not updated after a change for example. If it still doesn't work: could you post the script somewhere and/or tell what it should do?

Comment: http://notepad.cc/share/Ik652QwUMe you can look at this, thank you.

Comment: @AhmetSehaÇelenk Thanks! WHat is the key shortcut you are using?

Comment: Currently alt+o, the former was ctrl+shift+o,

Comment: @AhmetSehaÇelenk found the issue, will edited my anser :)